# GRASS 7.6 v.net.iso not providing output in QGIS 2.18

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-2, isochrone

There are simply two layers in [EPSG:31469](https://epsg.io/31469) both are located on the Server side, see image below:

- points `'HST_Bestand_GK5'`
- polylines `'vwESKN_1_25000_Teil'`

[image: input_data]

On my Windows 10 with QGIS 2.18 and GRASS 7.6, I am trying to execute the [v.net.iso](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.iso.html) algorithm. However, there are no outputs, logs, errors etc. What could be a problem?

[image: v.net.iso_working_window]

GRASS 7.6 setting looks as following

[image: settings]

I tried what was written in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85314/no-output-file-with-grassr-los), but my Log console looks okay, see below. Any ideas?

[image: log_menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied the folder with working shapefiles on my Desktop and executed the same algorithm in QGIS 2.18 with GRASS 7.4 // QGIS 2.14 with GRASS 7.2 and saved the output layer instead of working with a temporal one, everything worked well.

There was a problem with user allowances for the current project which was established by a colleague of mine, therefore the temporal output was simply lost in a different path.

Additionally, make sure that the working folder does not contain any specific characters, e.g. in my case ä, ü, ö, ß in its name.