# System couldn't find given path while running v.split

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis

I'm trying to run the Grass Tool `v.split` and get the following error message:

[image: example]

the grayed outline in German translate to `"The System couldn't find the given path"`

The `.exe`-files of the grass Tools are all in the following path:

> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\grass\grass7.6.0\bin

Any idea what problem might be? I get an error message for every gras tool I'm trying to use.

Here is also a Picture of the "Processing Options"

[image]

It says "activate; protocol commands; for Vectorlayer use v.external instead of v.in.org; protocol consol output; place of GRASS documentation"

Comment: Does your working path contain specific characters in it, e.g. ä, ü, ö, ß?

Comment: no, there are no specific characters

Comment: can you please share full settings of GRASS GIS in QGIS? similar to this example [GRASS 7.6 v.net.iso not providing output in QGIS 2.18](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326685/grass-7-6-v-net-iso-not-providing-output-in-qgis-2-18)

Comment: like the Image I just edited to the question?

Comment: These question/answer can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302446/error-using-grass-v-clean-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: Probably it is this bug? https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3925